# laracasts testdummy without laravel

Tags: laravel, testing, zend-framework

I've started using laracasts/integrated on my zend project, and am trying to figure out if I can use laracasts/testdummy too. I can't see how the database connection and models would work.

Is this not possible?

Comment: I have a hunch: can I use https://github.com/illuminate/database with eloquent models to simply define my database for the purpose of testdummy, but not actually use these libraries in my project? Does this seem like a crazy idea?

Comment: Or can I pass in an extension of Zend_Db_Table_Row which implements the TestDummy IsPersistable interface?